# Incorrect width returned sizeWithAttributes for different locales

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I have a UIButton whose size is computed based on a NSString `self.currentTitle`.
`self.titleLabel` is the UIButton Label.The API usage is below:

```
CGFloat textSizeWidth = [self.currentTitle sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : self.titleLabel.font}].width;
```

This text width returned is further used to set the UIButton's width as it is the quiet variant.It works fine for english locale but when i try for japanese characters the width returned seems to be incorrect as the button label is truncated.
self.titleLabel is a NSString so i am assuming it should work for japanese as well.Any inputs on handing this will be useful.

Comment: Same thing here but on macOS 10.11…

Answer (score 0):

This happens when all characters are Chinese /Japanese.
A possible workaround is to use an extra space in string and the length returned is correct now